# MySQL Query Too Slow For Limited Row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with mysql query. It is too slow about 101 seconds for limited 10 row. What could be the problem ?

Query is :

```
SELECT isteksikayet.BASVURU_NO AS BasvuruNo, isteksikayet.BASVURU_TARIHI AS BasvuruTarihi, mahalle.ad AS MahalleAdi, konular.ADI AS KonuAdi, 
sonucturleri.ADI AS Durum, isteksikayetdetay.GUNCELLEME_TARIHI AS BilgiTarihi, birimler.ad AS BirimAdi 

FROM isb_istek_sikayet isteksikayet
INNER JOIN tbl_sistem_mahalle mahalle
ON isteksikayet.MAHALLE_KODU = mahalle.kod 
INNER JOIN isb_konular konular
ON isteksikayet.KONU_KODU = konular.KODU
INNER JOIN isb_istek_sikayet_detay isteksikayetdetay
ON isteksikayet.BASVURU_NO = isteksikayetdetay.BASVURU_NO
INNER JOIN isb_sonuc_turleri sonucturleri
ON isteksikayetdetay.SONUC_KODU = sonucturleri.KODU
INNER JOIN mubim_birim birimler
ON isteksikayetdetay.DAIRE_KODU = birimler.kod
ORDER BY BasvuruNo DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: To determine the records to display the DB has to go through all because you order them

Comment: Do you have indices setup on the join columns?

Comment: @juergend How can I fix that ? I can not have permission to chance db structure.

Comment: Then there is not much you can do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, there is no indices. Also table ids are not unique.

Comment: Add indices to the join columns if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I asked for indexing than it is working fast now, thank you.

Comment: @EminÖzgünsür Glad you solved your problem, I think this was the biggest problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the query returns only 10 row, but it has to order ALL the rows of a six tables join, this can really grow out of control quickly (like it already did on your database).

To avoid that I would suggest to order ONLY the table containing the `BasvuruNo`column and extracting the first 10 records in a subquery, and only then join with the rest of the tables. This way you should avoid ordering an overwhelming amount of records